# 'scholar::get_impactfactor' gives incorrect impact factor values and journal names

Tags: r, google-scholar

I just started trying to get impact factor values using `scholar::get_impactfactor()`, but it keeps giving incorrect impact factors and incorrect journal names. I feel that the three journal names ("JAMA", "Kidney Int", "American Society of Nephrology") are quite 'standard', and wonder what I have missed.

```r
scholar::get_impactfactor(c("JAMA", "Kidney Int", "American Society of Nephrology"), max.distance = .1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Journal                            Cites ImpactFactor Eigenfactor
#>   <chr>                              <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS 28839         245.      0.0660
#> 2 CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS 28839         245.      0.0660
#> 3 CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS 28839         245.      0.0660
scholar::get_impactfactor(c("JAMA", "Kidney Int", "American Society of Nephrology"), max.distance = .5)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Journal                  Cites ImpactFactor Eigenfactor
#>   <chr>                    <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 LANCET                  233269         53.3      0.436 
#> 2 NATURE REVIEWS GENETICS  35680         41.5      0.0943
#> 3 NATURE                  710766         41.6      1.36
scholar::get_impactfactor(c("JAMA", "Kidney Int", "American Society of Nephrology"), max.distance = .8)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Journal                                         Cites ImpactFactor Eigenfactor
#>   <chr>                                           <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 JAMA-JOURNAL OF THE AMERICAN MEDICAL ASSOCIAT~ 148774        47.7      0.300  
#> 2 JOURNAL OF THE AMERICAN SOCIETY OF NEPHROLOGY   37796         8.65     0.0568 
#> 3 Annual Review of Nutrition                       5528         8.89     0.00523
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>